# Meaning of "interrupt time off"

Tags: meaning

> He interrupts time off to deal with a troubled horse.

What does "interrupt time off" mean here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That he ceases to be taking time off, or stops someone else taking time off.

That is, stops taking a break and relaxing or whatever (that's what "time off" means) so they can deal with a troubled horse.